# Adjugates and topological proof the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $F$ be a field, 
for $H \in M_{k \times k}(F)$, let $H^*$ be the adjugate matrix of $H$. (Where the adjugate $H^*$ is the transpose of the matrix of cofactors of $H$.)

I am trying to prove the following two results:

1) If $H, G \in M_{n \times n}(F)$, then ${(HG)}^* = G^* H^*$.

2) If $H \in M_{n \times n}(F)$ and $G \in M_{m \times m}(F)$, then
\begin{equation*} \begin{pmatrix} H & 0 \\
0 & G
\end{pmatrix}^* = \begin{pmatrix}
\det(G) H^* & 0 \\
0 & \det(H) G^*
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

My current idea, is that both of these results hold for invertible matrices (using that $H^* = \det(H) H^{-1}$, when $H \in GL_n(F)$). Then, using that the set of invertible matrices is Zariski dense $M_{n \times n}(F)$, deduce the result for all matrices.

This argument is very similar to the topological proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
To this end it would be useful to have a reference for a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem using algebraic geometry.
Alternatively, does anyone know of a reference which proves the two results.

Comment: $H^*$ is uniquely determined by the identity $H H^* = H^* H = \det(H) I$.  I think both of your formulas follow from that (together with the usual properties of determinants).

Comment: @PaulSiegel I agree. It's a reference for the proof that both my formulas follow from this property that I'm looking for.

Comment: @PaulSiegel, of course I guess [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293879/adjugates-and-topological-proof-the-cayley-hamilton-theorem#comment729433_293879) means "the map $H \mapsto H^*$ is uniquely determined by the fact that it is Zariski continuous and …".